Как сделать масштабирование содержимого формы (WinForms) при прокручивании колеса мышки?
Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы изображение в форме масштабировалось при прокручивании колеса мышки. По задумке масштабирование должно выполняться относительно местоположения курсора, но в реальности изображение дергается в произвольную точку (логику так и не уловил), а уже затем масштабируется относительно нее. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю неправильно? Заранее спасибо!
internal class Program : Form
{
    Point point;
    float zoomFactor = 1.0f;
    
    public Program()
    {
        Paint += MyPaint;
        MouseWheel += MyWheel;
    }

    private void MyWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        point = e.Location;
        zoomFactor += (float)e.Delta / 1200;
        Invalidate();
    }

    private void MyPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(point.X, point.Y);
        e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(zoomFactor, zoomFactor);
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(-point.X, -point.Y);

        var pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 4);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, 0, 0, 500, 500);
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Application.Run(new Program() { Width = 600, Height = 600 });
    }
}


попробуй внутрь компонента layoutTransform(или что то подобное) поместить свое изображение, с помощью этого контрола зум работает без проблем.

Спасибо за ответ! Это компонент из WPF, верно? Я пока WinForms осваиваю, тут вроде бы нет такого. Также у меня в данном случае не изображение, а рисунок (просто линия) на форме - экспериментирую, чтобы добиться правильного зуммирования, а применять планирую к MDI-интерфейсу.

Почему бы сразу не рисоввть заскейленую картинку с нужным смещением? Ну и панель с прокруткой может потребоваться.

По трем причинам. Во-первых, применять это я планирую к MDI-интерфейсу, где нужно будет масштабировать все окна внутри главного, и их может быть довольно много. Если делать как Вы предложили, получится слишком запутанная логика. Во-вторых, представьте, что понадобится выполнить "сброс" - возврат к масштабу 1 и дефолтным координатам. Сам холст можно сбросить одной командой, но вот окна уже не вернутся, т.к. их координаты изменились. В-третьих, нужно просто понять как правильно выполнять такое преобразование, а не изобретать костыли. Пересчет координат это подмена местами причины и следствия.

@aepot, если работали с программами для 3д-моделирования (вроде Компаса или AutoCAD), то в них масштабирование выполняется именно так, как мне нужно - центр масштабирования находится в точке расположения курсора.
